# Exercise 5.P. - The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure (2011), Bartle's book,

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working on the this exercise but I don't know how to prove it. I am new with this subject.
I know that I need to apply the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I think that there are little diferent because it consider |X| and not X.
I apologize for not present a point of start.

Let $f_n \in L(X,X,\mu)$, and suppose that $(f_n)$ converges to a function $f$. Show that if
$$\lim \int |f_n - f| d\mu = 0$$, then $$\int |f| d\mu = lim \int |f_n| d\mu$$
thanks

Comment: Find an inequality involving the three things: $\int|f_n-f|d\mu, \int|f|d\mu, \int|f_n|d\mu$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $|f|=|f-f_n+f_n|$. Using the triangle inequality
$$
|f| \leq |f-f_n|+|f_n|.
$$
Hence
$$
\int|f|d\mu \leq \int|f-f_n|+|f_n|d\mu=\int|f-f_n|d\mu+\int|f_n|d\mu
$$
and
$$
\int|f|d\mu-\int|f_n|d\mu \leq \int|f-f_n|d\mu.
$$
Again using the triangle inequality $|f_n|=|f_n-f+f|$
$$
|f_n| \leq |f-f_n|+|f|.
$$
Hence
$$
\int|f_n|d\mu \leq \int|f-f_n|+|f|d\mu=\int|f-f_n|d\mu+\int|f|d\mu
$$
and
$$
\int|f|d\mu-\int|f_n|d\mu \geq -\int|f-f_n|d\mu.
$$
Then it follows that
$$
\int|f-f_n|d\mu \geq \int|f|d\mu-\int|f_n|d\mu \geq -\int|f-f_n|d\mu.
$$
Since $\lim\int |f-f_n| d\mu=0$,
$$
\lim\int|f_n|d\mu=\int|f|d\mu.
$$

Comment: Good job.
It's seems perfect. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! ;)